In foundry I just want to compile single specific file
I build a foundry project to develop Ethereum contract and create multiple files in /src directory
src
 A.sol
 B.sol
 C.sol

If I use "forge build", it will compile all files. What if I just want to compile A.sol? What option I should use?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

take a look at this issue:
https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/6278
you can also like it (upvote) maybe they will build such a feature (or you could build it on your own)

I am thinking of contribute it.
